Preserving Event Handler after using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML"
I have an HTML Div element (lets call it ELEM) .
ELEM has an "onclick" event handler which does something .
I also use SPFX to create a Webpart and use it on the same page as ELEM.
I want to set ELEM as the webpart's child.
And for that I use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" .
The ELEM does appear as a child ,however the "onclick" handler stops working .
What am I missing?
edit: For plain react ie without spfx it works just fine see live
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/event-handler-inner-html-7m7gxz

If I understand correctly, you are copying an element residing outside of your SPFx webpart and then want it to appear inside your SPFx webpart.
This is a little unconventional, but if you need your ELEM to have a working onclick event, you need to register it.
Sample code:
const elemRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

useEffect(() => {
if (elemRef.current) {
 
  elemRef.current.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}

...

<div
  ref={elemRef}
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }}
/>



For plain react ie without spfx it works just fine see live https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/event-handler-inner-html-7m7gxz

The link you shared says "the sandbox.does not exist."

my bad ... please try now !!

Great. I see the oclick event is "hardcoded" within the element using the attribute. In this case it works after cloning. Now the next question is what is the element you are copying in SharePoint and how its onclick is defined. Can you update the answer with the sample HTML of this HTML element?

Thanks ... ELEM is just another Webpart which displays the events from a Calendar Webpart. When a user clicks on an event ,it opens in a new browser tab.

it's important to know the details of that "just another webpart". Because that's the source of your issue.
